# ANGULARJS: directive inside another directive doesn't have access to ng-model from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I recently had a coding challenge that I got rejected for because it was garbage. Didn't have a lot of time so I threw everything together in one giant HTML file/angular controller, so I'm in the middle of rewriting it in templates to try to make it more reusable. So far it's going well, but I'm having some trouble with an html template not being able to access ng-model. Whenever I console.log the ng-model, I get undefined.

Here's the top layer HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-8 box">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Companies</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div ng-repeat="company in companies">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Name: {{company.name}} <button ng-click="companies[$index].editCompany = !companies[$index].editCompany" class="pull-right">EDIT COMPANY</button></div>
                    <div class="panel-body" ng-if="!companies[$index].editCompany">
                        <p>Address: {{company.address}}</p>
                        <p>Revenue: {{company.revenue}}</p>
                        <p>Phone Number: {{company.phone}}</p>
                        <button ng-click="getPeople(companies[$index]._id, $index); companies[$index].viewEmployees = !companies[$index].viewEmployees">People Who Work Here</button>
                        <div ng-if="companies[$index].viewEmployees">
                            <show-employees-list></show-employees-list>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="companies[$index].editCompany">
                    <edit-company-directive></edit-company-directive>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the HTML for the directive:

```
<div class="employee-box" ng-repeat="employee in companies[$index].employees">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit pull-right" ng-click="companies[$index].editEmployee = !companies[$index].editEmployee; clickEdit()"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" ng-click="deletePerson(employee._id, $index, companies[$parent.$index].employees)"></span>
    <div ng-if="!companies[$index].editEmployee">
        <div>
            <p><b>Name:</b> {{employee.name}}</p>
            <p><b>Email:</b> {{employee.email}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="companies[$index].editEmployee" class="form-body">
        <form name="editPersonForm" ng-submit="editPerson(employee._id, $parent.$parent.index, $parent.index)">
            <input type="text" ng-model="nameEdit" id="nameEdit" placeholder="Employee" class="form-control" required></input>
            <input type="text" ng-model="emailEdit" id="emailEdit" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required></input>
            <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success form-actions">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the directive code:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
    angular
        .module('sigFig')
        .directive('showEmployeesList', showEmployeesList);

    function showEmployeesList(sigFigFactory) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'Directives/showEmployeesList/showEmployeesList.html',
            scope: '=',
            require: '^parentDirective',
            link: link
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attra, controller) {
            scope.deletePerson = function(id, index, employees) {
                sigFigFactory.deletePerson(id).then(function(response) {
                    employees.splice(index, 1);
                    return response;
                })
            };

            scope.editPerson = function(personId, index1, index2) {
                scope.person = {
                    name: scope.nameEdit,
                    email: scope.emailEdit
                };

                console.log('person ', scope.person);
            };
        }
    }
})();
```

I'm thinking it's some sort of scoping issue that I just don't see, and hoping someone can help. When I `console.log` that `person` object I get `undefined` for both properties.

Answer (score 0):

it's good idea to use `angular directive`, and also you need to read more about it:

> you just define `scope` as `variable` but it's `object`, and there isn't `scope.nameEdit` to console

```
app.directive("name", function() {
  return {
     templateUrl: "your.html", //it's string
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: { //it's object
        param1: "="  //var
        param2: "@"  //string
        param3: "&"  //method and etc   
     },
     link: function(scope){ //it's function
        //scope.param1
        //scope.param2
        //scope.param3
     }
  }
})

<name param1="{foo: 'test'}" param2="hello" param3="callback"></name>
```

with directive you can pass everything from your basic view (controller) to the directive, you can `$watch` value on change in your controller and more options.